# Putty for exhaust manifold leak

Tags: exhaust, exhaust-manifold, classic, campervan, sealant

Having some issues with a small exhaust leak from the exhaust manifold on my campervan. We got it taken to a mechanic to repair the manifold leak but he's ended up just making it worse. I dont have the tools to smooth out the Manifold myself, so was wondering if there was any putty that could withstand the temperatures of the manifold I could use?

Ive already had a crack at using fire putty - it worked perfectly for the first 20 mins but then failed, presumably it couldn't withstand the temperatures. But if someone knew of a type of putty that would work on exhaust manifold temperatures that would be fantastic.

Comment: The first [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=type+of+putty+that+would+work+on+exhaust+manifold) hit is for **Pyro-Putty** which seems to be designed specifically for exhaust systems.

Comment: Back in the day, the standard stuff for this was Gun Gum.  I don't know if they still make it.

Comment: Asbestos makes  best muffler sealant but is politically incorrect today. I made pretty good stuff with asbestos and sodium silicate.

Comment: @blacksmith37 for a moment I thought you were joking, because in UK it's been illegal to use asbestos in any product since 1999, but I see that's not the case in USA. [Mesothelioma.com](https://www.mesothelioma.com/lawyer/legislation/asbestos-ban/) says "*many products still legally contain up to 1% of the mineral*". Not that in itself could be dangerous here (it's the dust which problemmatic), but there are workers in factories that import and process it.

Comment: @Bren how old is the exhaust? One mechanic made it *worse* which suggests that it may be time to replace all or part of the exhaust system.

Answer (score 0):

Leaking exhaust manifolds are serious, as the exhaust fumes could leak into the passenger compartement.

A bandaid in form of putty won't stop the leak.

With a bit of luck you only need a new gasket.
Otherwise the manifold is cracked and needs to be welded (since it is cast iron you will need a professional welder) or replaced (ask at a scrapyard).

The bolts holding the manifold are notorious for being rusted. A oxy flame could be helpful. Cover the new nuts with anti-seize before assembly.